# Java development in Nvidia Eclipse-Nsight

Tags: java, eclipse, cuda, nsight

I've just installed Cuda toolkit 5.0 for Linux and am wondering whether it is possible to do Java development in Nsight. I have a Cuda project with Java frontend and this would make managing it a lot easier.

After all Nsight is based on Eclipse, and it hardly makes sense keeping two almost identical IDEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can install Eclipse Java Developer Tools in Nsight:

1. Go "Help->Install new software..."
2. Set "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/" into "Work with" entry field. This is Eclipse.org update site that hosts open-source Eclipse plugins.
3. Check "Programming Languages"/"Eclipse Java Development Tools"
4. Complete the wizard. Wait for JDT installation to finish (may take awhile to finish, depending on your connection and state of mirrors).
5. Restart the IDE.

You can now use all Eclipse Java Development features.

Comment: Many thanks. I wasn't sure which version of Eclipse was used for Nsight, Indigo makes perfect sense.

Comment: Nsight 5.0 is based on Eclipse 3.7.2 and custom build of CDT 8.0.2.